# Filter object error in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, lambda, filter

When I run this code in Python 3:

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
print( filter(lambda x: x == "Python",languages))
```

I get this error:

```
filter object at 0x7fd83ff0
filter object at 0x7feede10
```

I do not know what the error means - and it runs ok in Python 2.7.

Can anyone suggestion a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not an error - you printed an *object of type filter* as the `filter()` don't return *list* - it *constructs* an *iterator*, but only *if there is a request for it*.

The simplest solution is to use the function `list()` - it *requests an iterator* and returns the *list*:

```
print( list(filter(lambda x: x == "Python", languages)))
```

instead of your command

```
print( filter(lambda x: x == "Python",languages))
```

**Note**: It is similar to printing `range(10)` (which is an object) and printing `list(range(10))` (which is the list).

There are changes between `Python 2.x` and `Python 3.x` in almost all functions which returned a `list` in Python 2.x - in Python 3.x they return something more general and less memory consuming, something as **recipe how to obtain elements in the case of interest**.

Compare: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` and `integers from 1 to 9` (or `1, 2, ..., 9`).
 No difference? Try write down `all integers from 1 to 999999`.

Comment: Thanks a lot is very clear  ¿so the mesage is the memory address of the iterator?

Comment: Almost true - memory address of the **filter** object itself (as the *iterator* object is generated only in the case of need). It is common way how most objects are printed.

Comment: I allready did but i´m low rank only 5 points so the site dont consider my vote, but I´m very gratefull and pleased with your great answer, as soon as I get get more points (at least 15) i will vote you again..